# Generating Function for rational sequence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, generating-functions

I'm trying to compute the generating function for the function defined for $1\le N < \beta$,  $C_N = \frac{\beta}{N(\beta-N)}$.  I think my math so far is correct, but I don't know how to solve the differential equation at the end.  My work so far is below.  Thanks in advance!

$C_N = \frac{\beta}{N(\beta-N)}$

$N(\beta-N)C_N = \beta$

$\sum_{N=1}N(\beta-N)C_N z^N = \sum_{N=1}\beta z^N$

$\sum_{N=1}N\beta C_N z^N -\sum_{N=1}N^2 C_N z^N = \sum_{N=1}\beta z^N$

$\beta zC'(z) - (2\sum_{N=1}$ $N\choose2$ $C_N z^N$ + $\sum_{N=1}N C_Nz^N) = \beta\sum_{N=1} z^N$

$\beta zC'(z) - 2z^2C''(z) - zC'(z) = \beta\sum_{N=1} z^N$

$(\beta - 1)zC'(z) - 2z^2C''(z)=\beta \frac{1}{1-z}$

Comment: That is an [Euler equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html). Your tame computer algebra system (e.g. [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)) should finish it off. Getting the coefficients out of the resulting mess will probably just give you back the original relation you started with...